# Pandas печать на принтер

Tags: python

Подскажите - не получается отправить на печать(принтер) файлик, если в терминале командой print - все отображает.

Кусочек кода:

```
def print(self):

        df_orders = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, names=['Фамилия', 'Город'])
        df = (df_orders.head())

#Печать файла CSV - без проблем

        os.startfile(file_path, "print")

#Печать файла Pandas

        print(df) # отображение в консоль(все красиво)
        os.startfile(df, "print") # Выдает ошибку - TypeError: startfile: filepath should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not DataFrame
```

Comment: Сохранить в файл, потом печатать. startfile стартует файл (открывает файл в связанном приложении) с передачей дополнительных параметров, а датафрейм - это вообще не файл, это условно табличка в памяти.